# Android pre-3.0 memory question

Tags: android

I read that before 3.0 data like bitmaps is strored outside the heap. But where exactly is it stored? And how can I analize the amount of memory consumed by my bitmaps? That all about OOM exeption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are located in the native heap. For more info [Bitmaps in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945142/bitmaps-in-android). You can get runtime information about the native heap using these methods.

[getNativeHeapAllocatedSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#getNativeHeapAllocatedSize%28%29)

[getNativeHeapFreeSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#getNativeHeapFreeSize())

[getNativeHeapSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#getNativeHeapSize())

Comment: I can see that native heap constantly grows, until exceeds it limit. Am I right?

Comment: If you are only decoding Bitmap without freeing them - yes

Comment: Yes, I've got HashMap<String, Bitmap> and I don't remove bitmaps from it. Thanx for response.

Comment: It's good practice to call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle() when you don't need the bitmaps any more.

Comment: recycle is called on the destructor any way. Better just null them and wait for the GC do its job.