# Exception during fetching the image from webserver in android

Tags: android, webserver, android-asynctask, imagesource

Hi i am getting the following exception while fetching the image from server. I works for fetching 5-7 images after that got the following:

> 06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):
>   java.lang.InterruptedException 06-12
>   16:35:50.904: WARN/AsyncTask(717):
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1254)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:219)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:82)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:196)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerCancel(FutureTask.java:293)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.cancel(FutureTask.java:75)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.cancel(AsyncTask.java:325)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   us.bnn.news.IncidentDetailsActivity$GetImages.doInBackground(IncidentDetailsActivity.java:1691)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   us.bnn.news.IncidentDetailsActivity$GetImages.doInBackground(IncidentDetailsActivity.java:1)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
>   06-12 16:35:50.904:
>   WARN/AsyncTask(717):     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

I an using this method:

```
public static Bitmap getLargeImage(String imgUrl)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;               
        InputStream in = null;
        Log.v(TAG,"start fetchimg main images");
        try
        {             
            DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(imgUrl);

            HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);

            if (mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
            {
                HttpEntity entity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();           
                if ( entity != null) 
                {
                    in = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in, 8190);

                    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                    int current = 0;
                    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                        baf.append((byte)current);
                    }
                    byte[] imageData = baf.toByteArray();
                    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
                    if(in != null)
                        in.close();
                } 
            }                     
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.v("Error Fetching images from url",ex.getMessage());          
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you receive images in different threads? If yes, which class do you use to download the images? Standard HttpClient is not thread-safe, you should use ThreadSafeClientConnManager to get thread-safe one.

Comment: i have added the the question, can you please look into that and suggest me what to do?

Comment: It's not clear when the exception is thrown. From stack trace that you gave, it seem that problem is not downloading image, but something with AsyncTask...