# Why do I encounter 'out of memory' while enough memory is available?

Tags: android

Recently, I was developing an application for image browsing. One activity is to browse images in thumbnail view (Activity A) (one listview and nested some gridview), after showing the images, the user can tap one photo to enter full view (Activity B) then enter edit view (Activity C).

In Activity A there are many photos, so the memory usage increases (I didn't make cache size limited, 40313k/42503k), then I enter Activity B and release all caches on Activity A, I can see the memory dropping (26335K/42503K). However, when I enter Activity C, out of memory happens. I check the memory size, the free memory is still enough for allocation (52436K/65159K to allocate 7680016-byte)

BTW, I saw Grow heap (frag case), what is this? Could it be the reason?

Can anyone help?

Below is my log for memory

```
08-06 16:59:15.861: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1350K, 9% free 19414K/21319K, paused 32ms
08-06 16:59:16.064: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1350K, 9% free 19414K/21319K, paused 31ms
08-06 16:59:16.275: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1350K, 9% free 19414K/21319K, paused 34ms
08-06 16:59:16.463: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1350K, 9% free 19415K/21319K, paused 24ms
08-06 16:59:16.861: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1073K, 8% free 19699K/21319K, paused 18ms
08-06 16:59:17.338: D/dalvikvm(2923): GC_EXPLICIT freed 75K, 5% free 15254K/16007K, paused 5ms+2ms
08-06 16:59:17.400: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 954K, 5% free 20446K/21511K, paused 19ms
08-06 16:59:17.752: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 482K, 5% free 21515K/22599K, paused 20ms
08-06 16:59:22.377: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 578K, 5% free 22566K/23623K, paused 40ms
08-06 16:59:22.416: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 82K, 5% free 23245K/24391K, paused 15ms
08-06 16:59:22.424: I/dalvikvm-heap(29566): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.459MB for 1756816-byte allocation
08-06 16:59:22.439: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 24961K/26119K, paused 15ms
08-06 16:59:22.603: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 91K, 5% free 26006K/27143K, paused 16ms
08-06 16:59:22.744: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 383K, 5% free 26994K/28167K, paused 15ms
08-06 16:59:22.838: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 333K, 5% free 27931K/29191K, paused 15ms
08-06 16:59:22.932: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 352K, 4% free 28902K/30087K, paused 16ms
08-06 16:59:23.033: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 369K, 4% free 29863K/30983K, paused 16ms
08-06 16:59:23.127: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 358K, 4% free 30808K/32007K, paused 16ms
08-06 16:59:23.221: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 316K, 4% free 31764K/32903K, paused 16ms
08-06 16:59:23.322: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 359K, 4% free 32847K/33927K, paused 16ms
08-06 16:59:23.416: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 367K, 4% free 33798K/34951K, paused 17ms
08-06 16:59:23.510: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 380K, 4% free 34875K/35975K, paused 17ms
08-06 16:59:23.619: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 394K, 3% free 35951K/36999K, paused 17ms
08-06 16:59:29.392: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 530K, 4% free 36919K/38087K, paused 19ms
08-06 16:59:29.486: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1127K, 6% free 36575K/38599K, paused 17ms
08-06 16:59:29.494: I/dalvikvm-heap(29566): Grow heap (frag case) to 37.010MB for 1267216-byte allocation
08-06 16:59:29.510: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 127K, 6% free 37686K/39879K, paused 17ms
08-06 16:59:29.635: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 638K, 4% free 38582K/39879K, paused 18ms
08-06 16:59:29.713: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1110K, 6% free 38246K/40263K, paused 17ms
08-06 16:59:29.721: I/dalvikvm-heap(29566): Grow heap (frag case) to 39.577MB for 2246416-byte allocation
08-06 16:59:29.752: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_CONCURRENT freed 127K, 6% free 40313K/42503K, paused 2ms+3ms
08-06 16:59:39.963: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_EXPLICIT freed 14180K, 39% free 26335K/42503K, paused 3ms+6ms
08-06 16:59:40.010: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3581K, 47% free 22844K/42503K, paused 21ms
08-06 16:59:40.017: I/dalvikvm-heap(29566): Grow heap (frag case) to 29.722MB for 7680016-byte allocation
08-06 16:59:40.064: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 29% free 30342K/42503K, paused 2ms+8ms
08-06 16:59:51.111: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1803K, 33% free 28613K/42503K, paused 32ms
08-06 16:59:51.127: I/dalvikvm-heap(29566): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.355MB for 7680016-byte allocation
08-06 16:59:51.182: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 28% free 36108K/50055K, paused 2ms+3ms
08-06 16:59:51.392: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 32K, 28% free 36077K/50055K, paused 16ms
08-06 16:59:51.408: I/dalvikvm-heap(29566): Grow heap (frag case) to 42.644MB for 7680016-byte allocation
08-06 16:59:51.455: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 25% free 43577K/57607K, paused 2ms+8ms
08-06 16:59:51.549: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7507K, 38% free 36091K/57607K, paused 23ms
08-06 16:59:51.557: I/dalvikvm-heap(29566): Grow heap (frag case) to 38.629MB for 3456016-byte allocation
08-06 16:59:51.619: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 32% free 39464K/57607K, paused 2ms+3ms
08-06 16:59:51.682: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 32% free 39465K/57607K, paused 17ms
08-06 16:59:51.697: I/dalvikvm-heap(29566): Grow heap (frag case) to 44.488MB for 6144016-byte allocation
08-06 16:59:51.728: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 22% free 45465K/57607K, paused 1ms+3ms
08-06 16:59:51.900: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3717K, 25% free 43685K/57607K, paused 2ms+5ms
08-06 16:59:51.947: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 710K, 24% free 43965K/57607K, paused 21ms
08-06 16:59:51.971: I/dalvikvm-heap(29566): Grow heap (frag case) to 50.348MB for 7680016-byte allocation
08-06 16:59:51.978: D/dalvikvm(968): GC_CONCURRENT freed 409K, 4% free 14423K/14983K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-06 16:59:52.025: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 22% free 51465K/65159K, paused 1ms+9ms
08-06 16:59:52.127: D/dalvikvm(194): GC_EXPLICIT freed 983K, 19% free 20609K/25415K, paused 2ms+5ms
08-06 17:00:00.541: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 531K, 20% free 52444K/65159K, paused 43ms
08-06 17:00:00.541: I/dalvikvm-heap(29566): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 7680016-byte allocation
08-06 17:00:00.572: D/dalvikvm(29566): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 7K, 20% free 52436K/65159K, paused 27ms
08-06 17:00:00.572: E/dalvikvm-heap(29566): Out of memory on a 7680016-byte allocation.    08-06 17:00:00.572: I/dalvikvm(29566): "Thread-1522" prio=5 tid=16 RUNNABLE
08-06 17:00:00.572: I/dalvikvm(29566):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41c68058 self=0x3dc118
08-06 17:00:00.572: I/dalvikvm(29566):   | sysTid=29653 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4048232
08-06 17:00:00.572: I/dalvikvm(29566):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=0 core=0
08-06 17:00:00.572: I/dalvikvm(29566):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCopy(Native Method)
08-06 17:00:00.572: I/dalvikvm(29566):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.copy(Bitmap.java:403)
08-06 17:00:00.572: I/dalvikvm(29566):   at com.mtn.atc.photoedit.PhotoEditor.applyEffect2Bitmap(PhotoEditor.java:627)
08-06 17:00:00.572: I/dalvikvm(29566):   at com.mtn.atc.photoedit.PhotoEditor.access$21(PhotoEditor.java:624)
08-06 17:00:00.572: I/dalvikvm(29566):   at com.mtn.atc.photoedit.PhotoEditor$2.run(PhotoEditor.java:613)
08-06 17:00:00.572: W/dalvikvm(29566): threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a521f8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without code I could only imagine that overall, you are simply using too much memory in general.

1) Are you using an adapterview (like listview) in Activity A and therefore only loading visible thumbnails.
2) If you are loading full images and scaling them down for a thumbnail, it is worth using a scale factor when loading the full size image in Activity A.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

Specifically http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;

Bitmap thumb = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
```

This will cut down memory usage on Activity A dramatically.

Comment: Yes, I did so by scale the image to thumbnail. the problem is that there are too many photos, for example, 300+ photos. And I can see the memory increased and then decreased when I quit that activity. However, my next activity begin do memory allocation, it report OOM while the memory still be enought. That makes me confused. BTW, the device I used is Samsung Glaxy Nexus, and I think its memory is big(64M?)

Comment: What is the layout you are using to display them, surely it's not 300 photos on a single screen? So like my answer suggested you need to use an adapterview of some type so that you only load the photos that you need, and when loading the photos to use as thumbnails, use a scaling factor with BitmapFactory.

Comment: well, I use listview to load the items.And each item is a set containing some text and one gridview, which contains photos. each gridview has its own adpter. I use hashmap to cache the photos. I didn't do limit about the hashmap, it will grown when cache inreased. However, when I quit the activity, I will release all the caches. in next activity, the memory used dropped. such as GC_EXPLICIT freed 14184K, 46% free 26511K/48711K. And on next activity, when do allocation, it will report OOM like below: GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 44% free 36144K/63815K
Out of memory on a 7680016-byte allocation.

Comment: Are you caching the bitmaps? You can't do too many of those. I suggest if you implement caches for the Bitmaps, that you use SoftReference in your cache implementation so that if the GC needs memory it can remove the bitmaps from the cache.

Comment: hehe, I did use SoftReference like this Hashmap<String, SoftReference<bitmap>> imageCaches = null; The peak of memory I use is 30240K/45063K, when I leave that browse activity, memory drop like this: GC_EXPLICIT freed 15199K, 42% free 26233K/45063K. the continue task is begin edit the selected photo: decode the photo(2M) to RGB888, make a copy(used for undo), then add different effect. we have more effects, and it seems need load each effect's .so(through jni), will this cause the issue?

Comment: Is it possible to launch just the 3rd activity and see if it's causing a problem on it's own?

Comment: Yes, I simulate to launch 3rd activity. It will not crash at once, but crash after some effect switch. It seems the 3rd activity also got problem. Thank you, Pork.

Comment: Is it my understanding that you are applying filters? Perhaps for the activity, you should work with a much lower resolution version of the selected image. Then once the user is happy with the result, apply the filters to the full size photo in the last stage. This would at least save you from having to store an undo version when applying the filters as well as perhaps more memory from rescaling down into the ImageView.

Comment: Yes, something like fiter but more complex and we did as you said. I guess somewhere memory leaked. for 2MP photo, we need use RGB8888 pixel format, and make a copy(for undo), then it will cause 2 * 4 * 2 = 16M Bytes. (As Samsung Glaxy Nexus's screen is 1184 x 720, so I use 1600x1200 photo size for clear display)

Answer (score 0):

The allocation failure when there is seemingly enough free heap might be caused by memory fragmentation as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892676/android-bitmap-limit-preventing-java-lang-outofmemory). It could help to add `android:largeHeap="true"` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to try to increase heap size limit if you are targeting Android 3.0 or higher, but that's not a very reliable solution and will not eliminate fragmentation anyway.

Instead, I would suggest creating a static pool of Bitmaps that would be reused by new images.