# Memory metrics in android apps

Tags: android, memory-management, out-of-memory

I wrote Android application and it have some strange problems with **Out Of Memory** exception, which appears randomly. Yes, I know that problems with OOM exception usually because of images, and I used all what I can to avoid this problem.
The only way I could think to find the place where spend the memory is putting the logs with information about memory everywhere. But I really confused about which values ​​do I need.

I used next values:

- Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()
- Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
- Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
- Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()
- Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize()
- Debug.getNativeHeapSize()

And before OOM exception I have next values:

- maxMemory: 57344K
- freeMemory: 9581K
- totalMemory: 22407K
- NativeHeapAllocatedSize: 34853K
- NativeHeapFreeSize: 302K
- NativeHeapSize: 40060K
- lowMemory false

In this question [Android Bitmap Limit - Preventing java.lang.OutOfMemory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892676/android-bitmap-limit-preventing-java-lang-outofmemory) I see that used compeering ((reqsize + Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() + heapPad) >= Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()) ant [in this blog](http://organicandroid.blogspot.com/2010/12/totalfree-memory-on-android-apps-and.html) some strange information:

> Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize(); The free size is the amount of memory
>   from the heap that is not being used, because of fragmentation or
>   provision.

Also I can not understand haw can be OOM exception if (totalMemory: 22407K) much less than (maxMemory: 57344K).

Please help me understand how use this values.

Comment: total memory refers to max allowed memory per process, so it is normal to be 22MB out of 57MB. There are a lof of other processes so limiting their max memory is good