# Why is Android 4.0 / Ice Cream Sandwich allocating so much heap memory?

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I noticed that on my Galaxy Nexus that `android.content.res.Resources` is allocating about 11MB.  I discovered this as I was in the process of profiling things using DDMS and the "`Dump HPROF file`" option.  So, I spent two hours trying to see if the allocation was due to something in my code or supporting libraries. I removed all my data, a ton of classes, all my libraries, and saw no change. After placing a breakpoint in my code at the beginning of the `onCreate()` method of the activity, it showed that the 11MB allocation is already present.

After being thoroughly confused, I decided to connect my rooted Nook Color running CM7 to see what it was reporting for initial memory usage for the exact same application. The worst case memory "Problem Suspect" reported by the MAT weighs in at a mere 896KB.

Is ICS that top-heavy? Am I missing something here?  As far as I can tell, my application is functioning correctly, but having the heap usage indicate 97% full has me worried about potential failures.

If it helps, MAT was indicating that the primary objects consuming all the memory were Bitmaps, `BitmapDrawables`, and `NinePatchDrawables`. I don't understand where these allocations are coming from.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could try making a new application with the bare minimum, see how much its using there

Comment: I've given this a shot, off the bat in some cases with hardware acceleration turned on and the compat library linked, it can be less than 10% free heap on the GN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pre-Honeycomb (<3.0), Bitmaps were allocated in native heap and did not appear in Dalvik heap dumps as shown by Eclipse MAT, etc. This native allocation still contributed towards maximum Dalvik heap limits for an application, and still caused garbage collection to run at approximately the correct time when approaching a low memory situation. This usage can be measured with `Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()`.

Since Android 3.0 (including ICS), it now allocates the pixel data for Bitmaps in normal byte arrays in Dalvik heap. The practical effects of this are better/simplified garbage collection behaviour for Bitmaps (since they can be treated in a more orthodox way) and the ability to track Bitmap allocations in Dalvik heap dumps.

I do not think the actual memory usage for a particular application is significantly different between pre-Honeycomb and more recent releases, and that this is just a matter of an alternative accounting practice.

[Memory Analysis for Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)

[BitMaps in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945142/bitmaps-in-android/1949205#1949205)