# Why does the app take so much memory even before onCreate() is called?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, bitmap, oncreate

i've noticed a weird thing , and i wonder if it has always been this way:

on android ICS , i've set a breakpoint on the first line of the `onCreate` of the first activity that is launched (even on a hello-world app) , and i've chosen via the `DDMS` the option "`update-heap`" to see the current status of the memory .

i've noticed that the app uses about 10MB , 9MB are most probably of bitmap types.

what is going on? why does even a hello-world app uses so much memory? is it maybe for optimizations (pre-allocate memory before being used) ?

does it also occur on pre-honeycomb versions (where bitmap cannot be monitored and so i can't see it occur there) ?

Comment: This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221013/why-is-android-4-0-ice-cream-sandwich-allocating-so-much-heap-memory

Comment: but what is it used for ? what are the things that can cause it to take more space ? is there a way to minimize it? they say on google io video that it is for resources (and there it uses 3MB while for me it's 9MB) , but they don't explain more than that . here's the link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk&feature=player_detailpage#t=1904s